# Can I run a specific testng test group via maven?

Tags: maven, testng

I have several testng test groups, e.g. group1,group2,group3...
These are defined in my pom.xml and all get run when I execute "mvn test".  What do I need to run to only execute one group without having to modify the groups configured in the pom.xml.

i.e mvn test group2
    mvn test group1
    mvn test group3

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try

```sh
mvn test -Dgroups=group3,group2
```

Comment: Is there any way to run tests having BOTH `group3` and `group2`?

Answer (score 7):

I came across this question while looking how to disable particular test group and Radadiya's answer confused me a bit.

To run particular groups use this, as mentioned by Eugene Kuleshov. [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#groups)

```
mvn test -Dgroups=group1,group2
```

But to exclude some group, use this (note exclude**d** vs exclude). [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludedGroups) .

```
mvn test -DexcludedGroups=group3,group4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include and exclude specific group during maven test execution.

(1) Include Specific Groups

```
mvn clean test -DincludeGroups=TestGroup1,TestGroup2
```

(2) Exclude Specific Groups

```
mvn clean test -DexcludeGroups=TestGroup3,TestGroup4
```

Comment: See Mikalai's post below with links to maven documentation.

Comment: `includeGroups` doesn't seem to exist. Use the suggested `groups`

Answer (score 0):

You can also run tests that have a combination of groups. This will execute tests that are marked both with "group1" and "group2":

```
mvn test -Dgroups=group1&group2
```