# exclude maven module with intergration tests from test phase

Tags: maven, integration-testing

I have a multi module maven project with a structure

```
parent
  pom.xml
module
  pom.xml
  core-api
    pom.xml
  integ-tests
    pom.xml
```

I have maven surefire plugin setup for executing the unit tests '*Test.java' which are houses in the 'core-api' module.

We have slow long-running integration tests housed in a separate 'integ-tests' module. we use '*Test.java' for our integ tests as well.

We need to be able to compile all source code but want to exclude the 'integ-test' from running as part of the default maven 'test' phase. We plan to use a profile to enable the test phase of the 'integ-test' module. I don't want to use the 'failsafe' plugin.

A matrix outlining the combination is here

```
mvn              | core           | integ-test
test             | run unit tests | exclude
test -PintegTest | unit tests     | integ tests
```

I've defined the surefire plugin in my parent pom, with a property 'skip.integ.tests' which will be controlled via a profile '-PintegTests'.

```
<properties>
  <skip.integ.tests>true</skip.integ.tests>
</properties>
..
<build>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
</build>
..
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>integTests</id>
    <properties>
      <skip.integ.tests>false</skip.integ.tests>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

In my 'integ-test' pom, i've then overridden the 'maven-surefire-plugin' config and have the 'skipTests' configuration set to look at the value of the property.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skip.integ.tests}</skipTests>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

My problem is the integ-test module tests run in every case. Any ideas on where i'm going wrong with the setup?

Comment: "I don't want to use the 'failsafe' plugin.". Why not? It does what you want in a much simpler way. Just name your integration tests FooITs, and then you can use -DskipITs to disable them. (Or if you insist on a profile, have a profile that set the equivalent property)

Comment: Related: [maven: How can I skip test in some projects via command line options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123075/maven-how-can-i-skip-test-in-some-projects-via-command-line-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should name your integration tests accordingly to the [naming conventions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) of the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) which is intended to run the integration tests. Furthermore the **pre-integration-test**, **integration-test** and **post-integration-test** [life cycle phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) are intended for running those tests. This means in your case to configure the maven-failsafe-plugin accordingly to the documentation like this. The maven-failsafe-plugin bounds to the integration-test life cycle phase.

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

I would suggest to add the following profile into your integration test module like this:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>run-its</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This gives you simply the following options:

- `mvn test`

  running unit tests only
- `mvn -DskipTests=true test`

  running compilation etc. but no unit tests.
- `mvn -Prun-its verify`

  Running packaging etc. unit tests and **integration tests**
- `mvn install`

  Running installation without integration tests.
- `mvn -DskipTests=true install`

  Running installation without running unit tests nor integration tests.

Comment: thanks and i do hear you but i did make it clear i can't use failsafe as part of the solution. i'm in a situation where we have some brittle integration tests but we cannot allow an integration test failing to block a release, so i need some workaround where by the integration tests are only run in specific circumstances

Comment: Which i exactly gave you. Just in case of the activated profile `run-its` the integration tests where running otherwise they don't. (See [here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/maui/tree/master/src/main/resources/it-example-container-selenium) for full example in the mod-it).

Answer (score 1):

In your Maven build, you can exclude:

- compilation and execution of both **unit tests** (by Surefire plugin) and **integration tests** (by Failsafe plugin) by adding `-Dmaven.skip.test=true`
- execution of both unit and integration tests via `-DskipTests`
- execution of integration tests via `-DskipITs`

Instead, if you have your integration tests in a separate Maven module (i.e. integ-test in your case), you can directly exclude that from the Maven build via profile, like in below example -- see extract of aggregator's pom.xml and maven command line to be launched:

```
<modules>
  <!-- remove 'integ-test' from this list -->
</modules>
<profiles>
    <profile><id>build-it</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
        <modules><module>integ-test</module></modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and then `mvn install -P !build-it`