# Maven / Spring boot project - how to skip @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit

In my project there are many tests marked with @SpringBootTest which I don't regard as unit tests and rather as integration tests. So I would like to run only the unit tests when I execute:

mvn clean install

actually I want to run this command as part of pre-commit git hook but @SpringBootTest makes it longer to finish execution.

Is there a way to exclude the tests marked with @SpringBootTest? May be there is a pattern we can pass to maven that excludes/certain tests. Or may be write a test suite that includes the spring boot tests.

I did google search to achieve the above but don't have much luck.

Is there even a better way?

@Update: Constraint is maven pom file can't be modified.

@Update2: I have a solution that looks promising:

```
1. Use @Category("IntegrationTests") for @SpringBootTests tests.
2. Create TestSuite with excludeCategory:
@RunWith(CategoryRunner.class)
@ExcludeCategory("IntegrationTests")
public class TestSuite {
}
3. From mvn command line, run only TestSuite.
```

I am not sure this is the best. Appreciate anyone's better approach.

Comment: Naming convention as mentioned and using maven-failsafe-plugin for running integration tests. And by definition SpringBootTests are integration tests.

Comment: Move your integration tests in a separate module you only run when explicitly asking to.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-skipping-tests

Answer (score 7):

If you have different kinds of tests, and want to be able to specify which tests to run, you can do that with @Conditionals or with @Profile.

Examples:

- [`@ConditionalOnProperty("test.run.integration")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) The class will only be loaded by Spring when property `test.run.integration` is defined and not `false`.
- [`@Profile("integrationtest")`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) The class will only be loaded by Spring when profile `integrationtest` is active.

Comment: This strategy will need support from spring. While I am trying to run unit tests from maven clean install. So I am not sure whether your strategy will apply in my case.

Comment: @user1539343 Your entire question is about `@SpringBootTest`, so this is Spring, and therefore "support from spring" is a guarantee. Don't see what the problem is with that.

Comment: The problem I see is it trying to invoke spring IOC to do some bean creation etc. That really defeats the purpose of fast loading tests that is the gist of this question. The goal is to run the plain junits without any dependencies - all dependencies mocked. And while running tests, whatever test runner is trying to run the tests should simply ignore tests annotated with @SpringBootTest.

Comment: `ConditionalOnProperty` is for beans, not for tests.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on JUnit 4, use `@IfProfileValue` annotation on the test class or method.

Example:

```
@IfProfileValue(name ="spring.profiles.active", value ="IntegrationTests")
```

If you're on JUnit 5, as you should be by this time, use `@EnabledIf` or `@DisabledIf`.

Example:

```
@DisabledIf(
    expression = "#{systemProperties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('mac')}",
    reason = "Disabled on Mac OS"
)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-junit-jupiter) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

try either

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

or

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

For more options refer to below links

https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-skip-maven-unit-test/

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-skipping-tests

Comment: This is not related to the question.

Comment: @user1539343 Do you want to skip all unit tests or specific ones? Easy way to stop running junit tests through maven is to skip tests. this might solve the confusion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123075/maven-how-can-i-skip-test-in-some-projects-via-command-line-options

Comment: "In my project there are many tests marked with @SpringBootTest which I don't regard as unit tests and rather as integration tests. So I would like to run ONLY the unit tests when I execute:"