# Can I exclude a specific testng test group via maven?

Tags: java, maven, testng

```
 mvn test -Dgroups=group3,group2
```

Will execute groups3 and groups2 - as per [Can I run a specific testng test group via maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922581/can-i-run-a-specific-testng-test-group-via-maven)

I want to run all test that are *not* in a group. Is this possible through maven? E.g. I want to run all test that are not in group3.

"pseudo maven command"
    mvn test -Dgroups!=group3

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123075/maven-how-can-i-skip-test-in-some-projects-via-command-line-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to official TestNG documentation, see "Command Line Parameters" table here http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng , it should be possible with:

```
$ mvn test -Dexcludegroups=group3
```

However, for greater flexibility I would recommend to use [test suite configuration](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) file (aka `testng.xml`), the location of which can be configured via `<suiteXmlFile>` property of surefire-plugin, see: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

This will allow to take a full control over groups inclusion/exclusion, see: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#exclusions

Comment: When you run it with Maven with Surefire, the parameter you need is `-DexcludedGroups=groupfoo`. See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that using a beanshell in TestNG.

You create a suite xml file and define a beanshell as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groupToRun");
                !Arrays.asList(testngMethod.getGroups()).contains(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.GroupsPlayGround" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

This would basically cause TestNG to look for all tests that don't belong to the group which was passed via the JVM argument `groupToRun`

I have explained about this in my blog [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/).

You can also find more information about this on the Official TestNG documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell).